# Given the uniform PDF $ f_{X_1,X_2}(X_1,X_2)=1 $, Find $F_Z(X_1+X_2≤z)$

Tags: probability, integration

Consider the PDF of a uniform distribution:
$$
f_{X_1,X_2}(X_1,X_2)=1,\ \ \ 0<x_1,x_2<1
$$
Find the CDF of $Z=X_1+X_2$

---

The solution is:

For $0≤z<1$
$$F_Z(z)=\int^{z}_{0}\int^{z-x_1}_0dx_2dx_1=\frac{z^2}{2}$$
For $1≤z<2$
$$F_Z(z)=1-\int^{1}_{z-1}\int^{1}_{z-x_1}dx_2dx_1=1-\frac{(2-z)^2}{2}$$

For $z≥2$
$$F_Z(z)=1$$

---

My question is, why do we need to create separate integration for the two ranges of $z$. I could instead use

For $0≤z<2$
$$F_Z(z)=\int^{z}_{0}\int^{z-x_1}_0dx_2dx_1=\frac{z^2}{2}$$

Which is wrong however this is more reasonable. I find no reason to create a separate integration for $1≤z<2$. If I did, it is more "reasonable" for me to use this integral instead.

For $1≤z<2$

$$
F_Z(z)=\int^{z}_{1}\int^{z-x_1}_1dx_2dx_1
$$

Comment: If $1<z<2$ then $F_Z(z)=\int^{z}_{0}\int^{z-x_1}_0dx_2dx_1$ is wrong: for example $x_1 \le 1$ but that integral thinks it can be as large as $z>1$.  So you want $F_Z(z)=\int^{\max(z,1)}_{0}\int^{\max(z-x_1,1)}_0\,dx_2\,dx_1$

Comment: @Henry ohh right, it makes sense now!

Comment: Except I made a min/max error:  $F_Z(z)=\int\limits^{\min(z,1)}_{0}\int\limits^{\min(z-x_1,1)}_0\,dx_2\,dx_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a **geometric** intuition: the support of $(X_1,X_2)$ is the unit square, and so $F(z)$ is the intersection of this unit square and the triangle bounded by the axes and the line $X_1+X_2=z$.

If you draw it out, there are clearly 2 cases:

- $z\leq 1$ for which the line $X_1+X_2=z$ lies on or below (towards the origin) the diagonal (top-left)-(bottom-right) of the unit square
- $z>1$ for which the the line $X_1+X_2=z$ lies above (away from the origin) the same diagonal of the unit square

(The edge case of $z=1$ can be lumped with either $z<1$ or $z>1$.)

In the first case, the integral for $F(x)$ is just the area of a right isosceles triangle with side $z$. In the second case, the integral for $F(x)$ is the area of the unit square minus the area of a right isosceles with side $1-(z-1)=2-z$.

A more **mechanical** reason for 2 cases of $z$ is to ensure that the limits of integrations for the individual integrals for $X_1$ and $X_2$ remain between $0$ and $1$.